How to create a vector of generic functions in Rust
fn render_task_enter_field<W>(stdout: &mut W)
where
    W: Write,
{
    ...
}

I need to add this function to vector. I will iterate it and call each function.
I have tried Vec<fn(&mut impl Write)>, but it does not work
How can I call my function? I want to pass the variable described below to this function.
let mut stdout = stdout()
        .into_raw_mode()
        .expect("Cannot run raw mode")
        .into_alternate_screen()
        .expect("Cannot run alternate screen");

I use termion crate

A function pointer cannot be generic. Can you elaborate more on your use-case?

As per How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?, you need to make your types homogenous to store in a vector. Something like fn render(stdout: &dyn Write) instead perhaps. OR you need W to mean the same thing for all elements

You want this:
Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut dyn Write)>>

A vector of boxes containing a dynamic type of function that takes a dynamic object that implement write.
You can't add generic functions to an array since it's really just a whole bunch of separate function, but you can just make it take a trait object as an argument to get the same effect.
Full example:
use std::io::Write;

fn render_task_enter_field(stdout: &mut dyn Write)
{
}


fn main() {
    let mut k:Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut dyn Write)>> = vec![];

    k.push(Box::new(render_task_enter_field));
   
    for m in k {
        m(&mut std::io::stdout());
    }
}


Thanks for your answer, but I still have a question. How should I call my pushed function now? :) I will edit my question right now

@ArtemNovikov I added an example of calling the function. Box implements Deref so you can usually just treat it like the inner type. Nothing special is needed to call the function.

It could just as well be the more efficient fn(&mut dyn Write).

@ChayimFriedman True, in that case you couldn't add closures to the array

You can use this with mut
fn render_task_enter_field<W: Write + ?Sized>(stdout: &mut W) {
    writeln!(stdout, "Hello, world!").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut dyn Write)>> = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        v.push(Box::new(|stdout: &mut dyn Write| {
            render_task_enter_field(stdout);
        }));
    }
}


It could just as well be the more efficient fn(&mut dyn Write).
